# ping a server thru a specific port (fsockopen) in php

Tags: php, python, bash, sockets, fsockopen

function checkServer($domain, $port=80)
{
    global $checkTimeout, $testServer;

```
$status = 0;

$starttime = microtime(true);
$file = @fsockopen ($domain, $port, $errno, $errstr, $checkTimeout);
$stoptime = microtime(true);

if($file)
{
    fclose($file);
    $status = ($stoptime - $starttime) * 1000;
    $status = floor($status);
}
else
{
    $testfile = @fsockopen ($testServer, 80, $errno, $errstr, $checkTimeout);
    if($testfile)
    {
        fclose($testfile);
        $status = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        $status = -2;
    }
}

return $status;
```

}

the testserver is google.sk, and checkTimeout is 10 seconds. This actually works, but when i try to run it in a loop for about 50 times, and do other stuff (mysql queries and things like that), it's not slow, but it causes 100% load of my CPU until the script ends. It's a single apache proccess that drives my cpu crazy ... So i wanted to ask you if you have any ideas about it. maybe some tip how to do the same in python or bash or so will be appreciated.

Thank you for the responses :)

Comment: That's not "pinging", that's a denial of service attack and it's probably going pear-shaped because you'll be rate-limited on SYN packets and your script will be stuck in I/O WAIT for your 10 second timeout twice.

Comment: it's not like that ... it will be the user who wants to ping his server... im not gona ping random servers or so ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [CURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php)

this is an example how to conversion fsockopen to CURL 
[PHP fsockopen to curl conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957068/php-fsockopen-to-curl-conversion)

Good luck

Comment: hello, thank you very much for your response, but i don't think that's what im looking for, cause i only want to check whether some port of some server is 'opened' and if there is some service running on this port ... the code i posted works very well, and also it's okay when i do it in a loop for 200 times. but when i add some other code to it, it starts to drain a lot of cpu usage.